# Python: Appending an array like in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab

How do I initialize and append an array like in MATLAB

```
for i = 1:10
    myMat(i,:) = [1,2,3]
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "array"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) if you want an object similar to MATLAB's array constructs. There are many ways to construct arrays using numpy, but it sounds like you might be interested in [joining](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html#joining-arrays) or [appending](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html#adding-and-removing-elements).

However, the strictest way to do what the MATLAB code in your question is doing is to construct the array first, then [assign to it by slice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.empty((10, 3))
for idx in range(10):
    mat[idx, :] = [1, 2, 3]

print(mat)
```

This will output

```
[[ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this in Python without any libraries, then you can initialize an array with a literal and list comprehension like so

```
myMat = [[1,2,3] for _ in range(10)]
```

If you are coming to Python from MATLAB I would suggest looking into the library [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) which exhibits behavior very similar to MatLab matricies with special "numpy arrays". In Numpy you might do this like so

```
import numpy as np
myMat = np.empty((10,3))
myMat[:] = [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```
In [18]: import numpy as np

In [19]: a = np.empty((10, 3))

In [20]: a[:] = np.array([1,2,3])

In [21]: a
Out[21]:
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.]])
```